# Flex 4 Modules & Ant - Error: Could not resolve "" to a component implementation

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, ant, flex4, mxml

I can compile the main application but am having an issue with compiling a nested module.

I have the following application structure:

- src

  - MyApp.mxml
  - view

    - MyView.mxml
  - module

    - MyModule.mxml
    - view

      - AnotherView.mxml

When using the following command

```
<mxmlc file="${SRC_DIR}/${MODULE_DIR}/MyModule.mxml" 
  debug="false" 
  output="${OUTPUT_DIR}/${MODULE_DIR}/MyModule.swf" 
  locale="" 
  actionscript-file-encoding="UTF-8" 
  keep-generated-actionscript="false" 
  optimize="true" 
  fork="true" 
  load-externs="LinkReport.xml" 
  incremental="false">
 <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>
 <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/>
 <compiler.library-path dir="libs" append="true"> 
 <include name="*.swc"/> 
 </compiler.library-path> 
</mxmlc>
```

I get the following error:

Error: Could not resolve "view:AnotherView" to a component implementation.

I think the compiler might be having an issue with determining which "view" directory has the right mxml file ..

Any Thoughts? A detailed explaination with an example would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your src directory as part of the source-path as well. You basically haven't told the compiler where to find your code.